# SQL Server giving intermittant connection failures

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2000 running on Windows 2003 Server that is giving me intermittent connection failures.

The user connections are getting closed on waiting but mature connections.  Meaning when users are connected to an application that is running on this server, the programs start up fine.  The problem usually shows up after the connection has been sitting for a bit.  I'm wondering if there is some odd setting that is killing older, not active connections?

What could be causing this?  What can I check to further troubleshoot this.

EDIT:

Is it possible that my problems are caused by running SQL Server 2000 personal edition, where the old server that died and was replaced was on Standard?  I have no way to verify the old version, but is this possible?

EDIT: Well I upgraded the edition to SQL 2000 Standard, and there is nothing different in the behavior of the server.  So that wasn't it.

Comment: Can you explain "The user connections are getting closed on waiting but mature connections" in more detail?

Comment: @mrdenny -Please see edit.

Comment: There's nothing in SQL Server that just randomly starts killing idle connections.  I've left connections open for days without issue doing nothing. Either there's a network glitch or there's a problem with the client application closing the connection when it isn't expecting it to be closed.

Comment: @MAW74656 SQL Server 2000 is out of support. Better to upgrade to new version 2008R2 or 2012 along with Windows OS as well.

Comment: @Kin -I know that, but I have to get this working now, upgrade will have to wait.

Comment: What sort of perf mon investigations have you done?  I'd look at the NIC and disk right off the bat.

Comment: @TechieJoe -I'm new to this sort of issue, can you recommend counters to look at?  Also, I can look at NIC counters, but this is a virtualized Windows 2003 server running on VMWare.

Comment: Start with the individual counters LogicalDisk and Network Interface.

Comment: @TechieJoe - Any articles on this or suggestions for danger signs to look for?

Answer (score 1):

“I'm wondering if there is some odd setting that is killing older, not active connections?” – short answer is no.

This is probably network issue, or SQL Server being under big performance impact or DNS or something similar.

Is your application on the same machine as SQL Server ? Do you have any other issues? Can you run SQL Server from Enterprise manager w/o issues?

Comment: No, the application is a windows client Access application on our production floor.

Comment: If SQL Server is under performance impacct, it could start rejecting transactions?  What performance counters should I be watching to determine if this is the issue?